# How to create a custom sort method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to specify a custom block method to sort an object array by evaluating two properties. However, after many searches, I didn't find to any example without the `<=>` operator.

I want to compare `a` to `b`:

```
if a.x less than b.x return -1
if a.x greater than b.x return 1
if a.x equals b.x, then compare by another property , like a.y vs b.y
```

This is my code and it doesn't work:

```
ar.sort! do |a,b|
   if a.x < b.y return -1
   elseif a.x > b.x return 1
   else return a.y <=> b.y
end
```

This block is within a function `return` is exiting the function and returning `-1`.

Comment: why don't you use sort method?

Comment: @Gashner I'm using it, but I'm intended to customize the evaluation.

Comment: Why is `<=>` ruled out? Because you want to do it the hard way?

Comment: The question is already answered but I want to point out that the problem with your code is due to wrong if syntax. You can simply change it to
```
if a.x < b.x
  return -1
elsif a.x > b.x
  return 1
else
  return a.x <=> b.x
end
```

Make sure to `end` the if block. Also you are sometimes using `b.y` instead of `b.x`.

Comment: can someone explain me shortly what is (a.x, a.y, b.x and b.y).
what is the use of that in .sort method .
thank you for your response .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401061/custom-sort-method-in-ruby#answer-15401861) is provided by @AJcodez below:

```
points.sort_by{ |p| [p.x, p.y] }
```

The "correct" answer I originally provided, while it technically works, is not code I would recommend writing. I recall composing my response to fit the question's use of `if`/`else` rather than stopping to think or research whether Ruby had a more expressive, succinct way, which, of course, it does.

---

With a `case` statement:

```
ar.sort do |a, b|
  case
  when a.x < b.x
    -1
  when a.x > b.x
    1
  else
    a.y <=> b.y
  end
end
```

With ternary:

```
ar.sort { |a,b| a.x < b.x ? -1 : (a.x > b.x ? 1 : (a.y <=> b.y)) }
```

Comment: A multi-level ternary statement in ruby is discouraged for readability/maintenance reasons.

Comment: The answer below by AJcodez is better than mine here; use that instead.

Answer (score 33):

This will give you ascending order for `x` then for `y`:

```
points.sort_by{ |p| [p.x, p.y] }
```

Comment: +1 for `sort_by` and `Array#<=>` which has exactly the semantics OP desires.

Comment: This is _very_ elegant! Well done - should be the accepted answer, IMHO

Comment: `sort_by` will be slower for small arrays. Toss a big array or more complex accesses to the values that are the sort keys, and it can quickly outrun regular `sort` routines.

Answer (score 1):

We can do it with more simple way

```
ar.sort! do |a,b|
  [a.x, a.y] <=> [b.x, b.y]
end
```

Or

```
ar.sort! do |a,b|
  result = a.x <=> b.x
  next if result != 0

  a.y <=> b.y
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
# Ascending
ar.sort! do |a,b|
  (a-b).abs() > 0 ? a-b : 0
end

# Descending
ar.sort! do |a,b|
  (a-b).abs() > 0 ? b-a : 0
end
```

There's no need for the spaceship operator ( `<=>` ) - it seems to be superfluous in Ruby (in terms of syntax efficiency), because Ruby considers `0` to be true, and for this usage specifically (above), you can just put the explicit `0` in the ternary operator.

Comment: [`sort!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-sort-21) isn't [`sort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-sort) and will modify the receiver (`ar` in this case). While `sort!` is faster, that behavior is something to be aware of.